# Query string is too long

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I configured `web.config` file but still I got an error:

> Request filtering is configured on the Web server to deny the request
>   because the query string is too long.

[image]

Comment: Query string length cannot be controlled through the web.config file it's enforced by the browser - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812925/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-query-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`maxRequestLength` is for file uploads.

Try this instead under the `system.web` node

```
<httpRuntime maxUrlLength="1000" maxQueryStringLength="1000" />
```

Comment: check for a location node then in the web.config.... and how long is the querystring being passed in?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this to increase the limit

```
 <security >
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="[Bytes]" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
```