# Error : AADSTS90015: Requested query string is too long(while doing ADFS)

Tags: azure-active-directory, adfs, adfs2.0, adfs3.0

I am doing ADFS authentication, and when I click the **Sign In** button from Microsoft Teams, I will be redirected to my URL, and I am getting the following error after the pages gets redirected:

**AADSTS90015: Requested query string is too long.**

I have tried the following solutions:

[HTTP Error 414. The request URL is too long. asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23237538/http-error-414-the-request-url-is-too-long-asp-net)
and
[Query string is too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39072599/query-string-is-too-long)

But i couldn't resolve the problem, help me to figure out this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions in the two questions you linked are not complete. Try adding the following to your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxQueryString="32768"/>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

See:

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits

You may have to add the following in your web.config as well:

```
<httpRuntime maxQueryStringLength="32768" maxUrlLength="65536"/>
```

Of course these numbers are just examples and you don't have to use these exact values in these settings.