# Stuck in Azure Login Loop

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to login to the Azure Portal. My Azure AD account is associated with 2 tenants - my regular 0365 tenant and I also have an Azure AD B2C tenant as well. When I access the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/) in Edge, I get shown the following screen:

[image: Help us protect your account]

If I click on **Next**, I get taken back to the same screen as above. If I click on **Skip for now**, I get the following error screen:

[image: Error Screen]

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache including cookies?

Comment: Yes, I have tried clearing cache and cookies and also tried incognito window.

Answer (score 0):

- If it is SAML Request ,the query string size must have exceeded ,which should not increase  over the limit of 4096 bytes.
- Try using fiddler trace to check saml query string size and for it to
  be not included ,please make sure that the SAML Request is not
  signed.`The signature element is optional in the request and Azure AD does not support /validate signed authentication requests` according
  to [**Signature** - | Microsoft
  Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-sign-on-saml-protocol#signature)
- In [Azure AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-generic-saml-options?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#configure-the-saml-request-signature) , to disable the SAML request signature, set the
  `WantsSignedRequests` to `false` so that the  Signature parameters
  (query string or post parameter) are omitted from the request.

*To remove signature from SAML request in aadb2c*

```
<Metadata>
  ...
  <Item Key="WantsSignedRequests">false</Item>
  ...
</Metadata>
```

- In other  cases such as  oauth2  check the  query parameter like
  state parameter and get it addressed with the particular application
  vendor or **support team**.
- Also check [AADSTS90015 while doing ADFS - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51243350/error-aadsts90015-requested-query-string-is-too-longwhile-doing-adfs)

Comment: I don't think the issue is Azure AD B2C configuration specifically as this was all working fine. I think the moment I turned on Security Defaults in my main Azure AD tenant, this started happening.